# RabbitMQ Client / Server notify on Server disconnected

Tags: rabbitmq

I am trying to implement a basic

- Client(Receive Updates / Sends Request)
- Server(Receives Request /
  Sends Updates)

using RabbitMQ.

Here is what I want to implement

1. To notify client when the server is shutdown(all reasons leading to this(bug/lost connection etc....))
2. Notify the client when the server is up again

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You want to set the mandatory  flag when you publish(channel.BasicPublish...) and handle the Basic_Return event to indicate that there was a routing issue. Does not necessarily mean connection is down, but in my case I am using this as an alternative to connection is down, as when a message cannot be delivered / routed for my application purposes connection is down.